# Как в одной функции задать несколько критериев поиска?

Tags: excel

Как в одном условии собрать несколько критериев?

```
=ПОИСК("слово1"; $A1)
```

чтобы здесь были так же слова: слово2, слово3 и т.д.  Чтобы не городить несколько правил.

Хотелось бы видеть что-то наподобие

```
=ПОИСК("слово1","слово2"...; $A1)
```

Comment: Угу... и что должна вернуть формула, если есть несколько вхождений?

Comment: у меня разукрашивается строка), это неважно. не смог найти главное как вбить несколько условий, что б было лаконично

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно условие вхождения всех слов:

```
=И(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК({"мама";"мыла";"раму"}; "мама мылила спину папе")))
```

Если достаточно одного совпадения

```
=ИЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК({"мама";"мыла";"раму"}; "мама мылила спину папе")))
```

В фигурных скобках массив констант. Такая конструкция позволяет обрабатывать массив без введения формулы как формулы масива.

Если сравнивать нужно с несколькими ячейками - тоже можно, но массив констант применять нельзя:

```
=И(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК(A1:A3;"мама мылила спину папе")))
=ИЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК(A1:A3;D5)))
```

И в этом случае формулу нужно вводить специальным образом: перед завершением редактирования формулы нажать `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, при этом формула должна обрамится фигурными скобками (признак формулы массива).

Comment: не могу понять, это условное форматирование, у меня разукрашивается строка на основе найденного слова в столбце E. вставляю формулу сейчас =ИЛИ(ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК({"HP";"c++"}; $E1))) и пишет ошибка.

Comment: Об условном форматировании сразу нужно упоминать... В УФ нельзя применять массивы констант. оздайте именованный диапазон и в УФ ссылайтесь на него. Но это уже другой вопрос

Comment: -не знал. а можете подсказать как создать именованный диапазон? то есть из того что вы предложили выше?

Comment: `Ctrl+F3`, там создаются имена... Кому взбредет в голову искать здесь ответ на вопрос об именах ил УФ? Не разберетесь - создйте отдельный вопрос