# Условное форматирование именованный диапазон не работает

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Нужно выделить строки со словами word1, word2, word3

Создал именованный диапазон A1:A10 и присвоил ему имя "исключения"
Создал правило условного форматирования =ПОИСК(исключения; $E1) (как понятно искомые слова должны попадаться в столбце E).
Короче ищет в именованном диапазоне только по слову в ячейке A1. Если вбиваю слова в A2, A3 и т.д. то уже не ищет. 
Почему?

Comment: Где создали? Покажите сылку на пример

Comment: есть таблица A,B,C,D,E , в E есть определенные слова на которые должна происходить реакция всей строки, то есть окрашиваться вся строка. Всё это работает если я просто создаю правило в УФ =ПОИСК("word"; $E1). Всё тоже самое я хочу реализовать через ссылку на именнованный диапазон A1:A10 на другом Листе, что бы в итоге вбить в шаблон несколько слов word1 word2 word3 и т.д.

Comment: Вы спрашивали о масиве констант при использовании УФ. Я советовал создать именованный диапазон. Сейчас Вы спрашиваете о диапазоне ячеек. Я же Вам показал в прошлом вопросе (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1018875/Как-в-одной-функции-задать-несколько-критериев-поиска), как написать формулу массива. При этом именованный диапазон не нужен.Что же Вы все в кучу мешаете?